# Html.DropDownList renders different HTML. hidden select and visible list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am new to ASP.NET MVC but i have worked on ASP.NET WebForms.
i am trying to create a dropdownlist. i read article [how to populate dropdownlist](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/).
here is my code
Controller:

```
 ViewData["Categories"] = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "cate 1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "cate 2", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "cate 3", Value = "3"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "cate 4", Value = "4"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "cate 5", Value = "5"}
        };
        return View();
```

View:

```
 <div>
                @Html.DropDownList("Category",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"])
                
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Categories"]);
            </div>
```

Model:

```
    public class Home {
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public List<string> CategoryList { get{return new List<string>(){"cate1","cate2","cate3","cate4",};} }
}
```

this is named after Home because i am using it as viewModel. actual model classes are different not interated yet.

here is what i get as output:

[output html code in browser inpect section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfvYs.png)

can abybody help how to get onlu select part without `display:none`?

Comment: It looks like you may have some JavaScript plugin which is replacing `<select>` elements with styled `<div>` elements.

Comment: Have you tried adding your own CSS like   @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Categories"], new { @class="dropdown" }); or replace the @class=dropdown with style = "display:none"; ?

Comment: @David i will have a look in js libs as i am using template for this UI and template may comtain some code like as i have experienced in another template... i am backend dev that is why i am so weak in frontend development

Comment: Thanks @David, it was **jquery.nice-select.min.js** that was ruining select element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @David in comment, it was js library named **jquery.nice-select.min.js** that was generating such result. 
apologies